# Rails 4: I get squares icons instead of icomoon icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, asset-pipeline, assets

in application.rb I have:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
config.assets.precompile += [
  '*.eot',
  '*.svg',
  '*.ttf',
  '*.woff'
]
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
```

I extracted my custom icons from icomoon, I added the fonts in app/assets/fonts, I added the icomoon css file in app/assets/stylesheets/_icons.scss (called from application.css.scss)

```
/* In _icons.scss */
@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?-d9yq0q');
src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix-d9yq0q') format('embedded-opentype'),
...
```

In my view:

```
<span class="icon-my-custom-icon"></span>
```

=> and the result is a square icon, instead of my icon...

Does anyone have an idea of why the icon is not accepted ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from the url in @font-face

With this definition of src:url, it works:

```
@font-face {
font -family: 'icomoon';
src:url('icomoon.eot?-d9yq0q');
...
```